# Problem in getting unique elements from list of tuples

Tags: python, python-2.7

I got sample input as `a=[(1,2),(2,3),(1,1),(2,1)]`, and the expected ouput is `a=[(1,2),(2,3),(1,1)]`.

Here, (2,1) is removed, since the same combinational pair (1,2) is already available. I tried below code to remove duplicate pairs

```
map(tuple, set(frozenset(x) for x in a))
```

However, the output is `[(1, 2), (2, 3), (1,)]`. How to get (1,1) pair as (1,1) instead of (1,).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a dict instead of a set to map the frozensets to the original tuple values. Build the dict in reversed order of the list so that duplicating tuples closer to the front can take precedence:

```
{frozenset(x): x for x in reversed(a)}.values()
```

This returns:

```
[(1, 2), (2, 3), (1, 1)]
```

Comment: No, that would result in `[(2, 1), (2, 3), (1, 1)]` instead, which is not what the OP wants. The OP specifically says that items that come first in the list should take precedence over the latter ones with the statement "Here, (2,1) is removed, since the same combinational pair (1,2) is already available". The dict constructor always lets the latter items with duplicating keys take precedence, so to make the former items take precedence instead one has to process the list in reversed order.

Answer (score 1):

This is one approach using `sorted`

**Ex:**

```
a=[(1,2),(2,3),(1,1),(2,1)]
print set([tuple(sorted(i)) for i in a])
```

**Output:**

```
set([(1, 2), (2, 3), (1, 1)])
```